# how to set different minimum order amount wrt different zip code in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have two array's of postal codes with both a different minimum order amount, how could I implement this? If you have two arrays of postal codes with different order amounts. Is that possible? For Pincode 10001 & 10002 = 200 min order value and for Pincode 10003, 10004 = 300 min. order value... How is it possible to implement this. Is there any code snippet available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_checkout_process` action hooks which allow you to validate checkout before placing an order.

Create an array with postal code and its value like below.

```
$minimum = array(
    '10001' => 200,
    '10002' => 200,
    '10003' => 300,
    '10004' => 300
);
```

You can get cart subtotal with `WC()->cart->subtotal` and compare it with the minimum postal code amount.

**Complete code.** Code will go in your active theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'set_a_minimum_order_amount_per_zip_code', 9999999 );
function set_a_minimum_order_amount_per_zip_code() {
    global $woocommerce;

    //add postal code to array with value the minimum amount without spances//
    $minimum = array(
        '10001' => 200,
        '10002' => 200,
        '10003' => 300,
        '10004' => 300
    );
    
    $billing_postcode = isset( $_POST["billing_postcode"] ) ? str_replace( " ", "", $_POST["billing_postcode"] ) : "";
    
    if ( array_key_exists( $billing_postcode, $minimum ) &&  ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum[$billing_postcode] )  ){
          wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf(  __( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.', 'woofood-plugin' ) , 
                    wc_price( $minimum[$billing_postcode] ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
                ), 'error' 
            );

    } 
}
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I have implemented the same code but It is not working.

Comment: Can you share your site URL? and, Where you add the code?

Comment: I have used Code Snippets to add the function code. Here is the link: https://mofood.co.in/stores/ The Pincode I used in the code is as mentioned: $minimum = array(
    '764059' => 99,
    '764071' => 299
);

Comment: Hmm, right on your site it's not working. I have tested with one order. Then it's required to debug.

Comment: I have activated the code again, You can check now.

Comment: it's required to debug.